# Slider Next Previous carousel functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery carousel slider where I want,

1) On pageload, the previous button should be hided

2) When Click on right, both should be visible

3) On last of the Image, I want the Right should be hided

My class for

*Previous --> ".left"*

*Next --> ".right"*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.left').hide();
  });
  if($('.right').click(function () {
      $('.left').show();
  }));  </script>
```

I did not get how to get the last image that's why i asked the question

Comment: Paste the code of what you have tried so far

Comment: What carousel control are you using? How are the elements loaded into the carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IF: 
`$('.right').click(function () {
      $('.left').show();
  });`

Comment: Please read my whole question, it is not sufficient what I want